# Python write a program Sort by the medal count. Save the three countries with the highest medal count to the list, 'top_three'

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code is:

```
medals = {'Japan':41, 'Russia':56, 'South Korea':21, 'United States':121, 'Germany':42, 'China':70}
def g(k,d):
    return d[k]
ks = medals.keys()
top_three = sorted(ks,key=lambda x : g(x,medals),reverse = True)
```

Actual Result :

```
['United States','China','Russia','Germany','Japan','South Korea']
```

But want to that result

```
['United States','China','Russia']
```

How it's possible please help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
medals = {'Japan':41, 'Russia':56, 'South Korea':21, 'United States':121, 'Germany':42, 'China':70}
def g(k,d):
    return d[k]
ks = medals.keys()
top_three = sorted(ks,key=lambda x : g(x,medals),reverse = True)[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the delimiter of three items only to your sorted results:

```
top_three = sorted(ks,key=lambda x : g(x,medals),reverse = True)[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
required = list(dict(sorted(medals.items(), key = lambda x: x[1],reverse= True)).keys())[:3]

other_approach =list(map(lambda x: x[0],sorted(medals.items(), key = lambda x: x[1],reverse= True)))[:3]
```